# Calculation on every dataset entry in Vaex

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

I wish to transform every column in a dataset so its entries are between 0 and 1 based on the min/max of a column. I get the min/max of each column with `df.minmax(col_names)` and then want to find the column width `col_width = col_max - col_min`. With this I wish to transform the data `df = (df - col_min)/col_width`.

How can I perform this opperation so that every entry is calcualted based on the column in belongs to?

Comment: you can use `.apply()` to run function on every column separately. And inside this function you can calculate `col_min`, `col_max`, `col_width` and `(column - col_min)/col_width)`

Comment: I't not sure but you simply calculate `normalize()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with vaex. Consider this example:

```py
import vaex
import vaex.ml

df = vaex.example()

# functional API
df_with_scaled_features = df.ml.minmax_scaler()

# scikit-learn like API
scaler = vaex.ml.MinMaxScaler()
df_with_scaled_features_again = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

Of course you can choose to do the maths yourself, but why bother when this is implemented on the vaex side in an efficient way.